# PInvoke WindowsAPI CreateFile from C#

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, marshalling

When PInvoking the WindowsAPI CreateFile from a c# program what is the best practice:  calling the generic CreateFile, ANSI CreateFileA, or the Unicode CreateFileW version?

Each of the API's has a different signature for the relevant CharSet:

```
// CreateFile generic
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile (
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpFileName,
    ...

 // CreateFileA ANSI 
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
 public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFileA (
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpFileName,
    ...

// CreateFileW Unicode
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFileW (
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpFileName,
    ...
```

According to Microsoft documentation<sup>1</sup>, for C# the default CharSet is Charset.ANSI.  That seems really strange since strings in C# are Unicode.  If the documentation is right, it means that CreateFile will ultimately call CreateFileA at runtime (with appropriate conversions to ANSI to and fro along the way).

Another Microsoft doc<sup>2</sup> says, "When the CharSet is Unicode or the argument is explicitly marked as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWSTR)] and the string is passed by value (not ref or out), the string will be pinned and used directly by native code (rather than copied)."  This seems great for avoiding copying potentially large strings and providing max performance.

Assume that I want to call the CreateFile flavor that works optimally with C# strings, has best performance, minimal casting / translations, works on Windows x64 OS and secondarily has maximum portability.

Approach 1:  Call generic CreateFile but change signature to CharSet.Unicode.
This may be a problem because CreateFile marshals the lpFileName as UnmanagedType.LPTStr whereas CreateFileW marshalls it as UnmanagedType.LPWStr.  It seems like the marshaling would have to perform conversions? to get the right LP type (more than once).  Another inefficiency is that CreateFile would have to call CreateFileW internally.  Also, I want to make sure the "pinning" is happening for max performance and I'm not sure that would happen here.

Approach 2:  Call generic CreateFile with signature CharSet.Auto
This seems to provide maximum portability for target OS but will wind up calling CreateFileA internally which is inappropriate for C# strings (Unicode).

Approach 3:  Call CreateFileW directly.
This also seems less than optimal because if I am compiling for a different target OS like Win x86 (that uses only ANSI strings) than the program will not be able to run at all.

It seems like Approach 1 would be best but the MarshalAs LPTStr doesn't look right to me (considering that the CreateFileW version marshals as LPWStr).

I would appreciate any help you can give on this.  I have been digging through dozens of conflicting webpages and can not find a definitive answer.

References:

<sup>1</sup> [DllImportAttribute.CharSet Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset?view=netframework-4.7.2)

<sup>2</sup> [Native interoperability best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices)

<sup>3</sup> [Copying and Pinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning)

Comment: I'll recommend you to use unicode version, i.e, `CreateFileW`, because call to `CreateFileA` converts your string encoding to unicode and indirectly and make a call to `CreateFileW` and in generic ones it is compiler dependent,  it will either use `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW`. But I am still wondering why don't you use DotNet api for this.

Comment: 1 and 3 are actually just the same. But there's no point in you doing anything other than calling the W functions directly.

Comment: Can't you use a `FileStream` instead? If you need access to the underlying OS handle, use the [`SafeFileHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.safefilehandle?view=netcore-2.2) property.

Comment: CharSet.Ansi is the default because .NET 1.x and .NET 2.0 still supported Win98.  An OS version that did not yet support Unicode.   And pinvoke was meant to interop with C code, wchar_t did not become available until C99 and it was not a popular standard.  Those days are long gone, you do not like the lossy conversion you get from trying to map strings to the default code page.  Even though it is not much of a problem for device names.  Under the hood the call is slower because CreateFileA() calls CreateFileW(), after converting the string to Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses UTF-16 LE character encoding internally<sup>1</sup>. When you call the ANSI version of a Windows API, the system will convert the input to UTF-16 (using the calling thread's current code page), call into the Unicode version, and convert the output back to ANSI encoding. This is both needlessly costly as well as lossy: not every Unicode string can be represented using ANSI encoding. The conversion also imposes arbitrary size limitations on input and output buffers ([CreateFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) limits the file name length to 260 ANSI code units).

With this in mind you will want to make sure to always call the Unicode version of the Windows API. This provides maximum performance on all supported versions of Windows, as well as guards against loss of information when converting from Unicode to ANSI. Whether you use `CharSet.Auto` and `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)` or `CharSet.Unicode` and `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)` amounts to the same<sup>2</sup>, and is a matter of personal preference. [Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices#dllimport-attribute-settings) being explicit, i.e. explicitly name the Unicode version (`CreateFileW`) and specify Unicode encoding as well as wide character string types (the 3rd option in your question).

---

<sup>1</sup> With the exception of Windows 95/98/ME, collectively referred to as Win9x. None of them are officially supported.

<sup>2</sup> [`CharSet.Auto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/specifying-a-character-set?view=netframework-4.7.2#string-marshaling-and-name-matching) *"chooses between ANSI and Unicode formats at run time, based on the target platform"*, so it isn't identical to `CharSet.Unicdoe` in theory. However, all supported platforms use Unicode encoding in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Call `CreateFileW`. C# strings are always Unicode and there is no reason to make conversions to ASCII and back to Unicode. About "generic" `CreateFile` - I am not 100% sure but for most API functions the generic is a C macro. The real exported functions are `A` and `W` versions. You may think about `CreateFileA` (ASCII version) only if you run Windows 95/98/Me. For 2000/XP/7/10 Unicode (UTF-16) strings are the default.